# How to stop player from pushing NPCs while moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my problem today is simple (two problems if you count the fact that English isn't my first language), yet I can't manage to get a hold of it. I'm trying to make an up down game in c# and I'm trying to improve the movement scripts before working on anything else (since I don't want to resolve major bugs later).

The problem is that as soon as the player comes in contact with the NPC, it should stop moving in its general direction (it can move in 8 directions, using combinations of the W A S D keys). The NPC movement doesn't give any problems, it stops moving as soon as it perceives the player. Instead, when the player collides with the NPC it keeps on moving in that direction pushing it for what feels like half a second before stopping (as it should). So, to summarize, it doesn't immediately stop, which is unnerving since I've tried many things to make it stop (including freezing the position of the NPC but that just made things worse).

Now the codes:

The NPC movement code:

```
public class NPCFreeMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 2f;    //how fast does the npc move
    public float maxIdleTime = 3f; //max time the npc spends idling
    public float maxChooseTime = 20f;    //max time he spends moving
    public float chooseDirTime = 0; //if 0, he chooses a direction

    //possible directions
    readonly Vector3[] directions = {Vector3.down, new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0), Vector3.left, new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0), Vector3.up,
                            new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0), Vector3.right, new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0)};
    public int dir; //current direction

    public bool canMove = true; //pretty self explainatory
    public bool idle = true;    //is the npc idle
    public bool chase = false; //is the npc chasing after the player

    public Vector3 goTo;    //where to go if it's chasing after something

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Idle(maxIdleTime));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        chase = GetComponent<NPCLookForPlayerScript>().found;


        if(canMove && !idle)
        {
            //move in the chosen direction
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + directions[dir], Time.deltaTime * speed);

            if (chooseDirTime > 0)  //decrease movement time
            {
                chooseDirTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                if(chase)      StartCoroutine(Idle(0));
                else            StartCoroutine(Idle(Random.Range(0, maxIdleTime)));
            }
        }
    }

    //npc goes idle, then chooses a direction
    public IEnumerator Idle(float f)
    {
        idle = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(f);
        idle = false;

        //here he chooses the direction depending of wether he's roaming or chasing
        if (chase)
        {
            ChooseDirection();
            chooseDirTime = maxChooseTime/4;
        }
        else
        {
            dir = Random.Range(0, directions.Length);
            chooseDirTime = maxChooseTime;
        }
    }

    //chooses a direction to take
    void ChooseDirection()
    {
        Vector3 v = goTo - transform.position;  //to check where to go
        if (Mathf.Abs(v.x) <= 0.5)
        {
            if (v.y < 0)    dir = 0;    //go down
            else            dir = 4;    //go up
        }
        if (Mathf.Abs(v.y) <= 0.5)
        {
            if (v.x < 0)    dir = 2;    //go left
            else            dir = 6;    //go right
        }
        if (v.x < 0.5 && v.y < 0.5) dir = 1;    //go down/left
        if (v.x < 0.5 && v.y > 0.5) dir = 3;    //go up/left
        if (v.x > 0.5 && v.y > 0.5) dir = 5;    //go up/right
        if (v.x > 0.5 && v.y < 0.5) dir = 7;    //go down/right
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c)
    {
        if(c.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle")  //stop and choose a new direction
        {
            StartCoroutine(Idle(Random.Range(0, maxIdleTime)));
        }
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player")   //stop
        {
            canMove = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D c)
    {
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player")   //resume chasing the player
        {
            canMove = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The player's movement script:

```
public class PlayerFreeMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed = 2.0f; //movement speed

    //where he's facing
    public bool up;
    public bool down;
    public bool left;
    public bool right;

    public bool idle; //false if a movement button is pressed
    public bool canMove = true;

    //movement direction
    public float dx;
    public float dy;
    public Vector3 v;

    CollisionScript cs; //collision script

    void Start()
    {
        down = true;
        cs = GetComponent<CollisionScript>();
    }

    void Update()   //move stickman in the direction of the keys and maintain the direction he's facing with animations
    {
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;

        if (!(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))) //check if idle
        {
            idle = true;
            v = new Vector3();
        }

        else    //the player's moving
        {
            idle = false;
            AllFalse();
            //set dx and dy
            if (canMove && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                if(!cs.hitRight)     dx = 1;
                right = true;
            }
            if (canMove && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                if (!cs.hitLeft)    dx = -1;
                left = true;
            }
            if (canMove && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                if (!cs.hitUp)     dy = 1;
                up = true;
            }
            if (canMove && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                if (!cs.hitDown)     dy = -1;
                down = true;
            }

            //create the motion vector
            v = new Vector3(dx, dy, 0);

            if(dx !=0 && dy != 0)
            {
                v = v / 2;
            }
        }
        //move
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + v, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    //avoid bug by deactivating all direction booleans before changing one
    void AllFalse()
    {
        up = false;
        down = false;
        left = false;
        right = false;
    }
}
```

And finally, the collision script used to detect collisions in its path

```
public class CollisionScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    //where is the wall
    public bool hitDown= false;
    public bool hitLeft = false;
    public bool hitRight = false;
    public bool hitUp = false;

    //gizmos
    public float collisionRadius = 0.5f;
    public Vector2 downOffset = new Vector2(0, -0.5f);
    public Vector2 rightOffset = new Vector2(0, 0.5f);
    public Vector2 leftOffset = new Vector2(-0.5f, 0);
    public Vector2 upOffset = new Vector2(0, 0.5f);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        hitDown = Physics2D.OverlapCircle((Vector2)transform.position + downOffset, collisionRadius).gameObject!=gameObject;
        hitRight = Physics2D.OverlapCircle((Vector2)transform.position + rightOffset, collisionRadius).gameObject != gameObject;
        hitLeft = Physics2D.OverlapCircle((Vector2)transform.position + leftOffset, collisionRadius).gameObject != gameObject;
        hitUp = Physics2D.OverlapCircle((Vector2)transform.position + upOffset, collisionRadius).gameObject != gameObject;
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;

        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere((Vector2)transform.position + downOffset, collisionRadius);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere((Vector2)transform.position + rightOffset, collisionRadius);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere((Vector2)transform.position + leftOffset, collisionRadius);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere((Vector2)transform.position + upOffset, collisionRadius);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a few problems here.  The first problem is that I assume that your player has a collider attached to it, right?  In that case, even when your player hits your NPC, `OverlapCircle` may be returning your player's collider instead of your NPC's collider.

Comment: Another problem is that your game is dependent on having `CollisionScript.Update` called before `PlayerFreeMovement.Update` during each game loop.  Because if they get called in the wrong order, your player will move before he knows he's collided with something.

Comment: For all the look and move directions I strongly recommend to use an `enum` since they are all exclusive and only can be one at a time like e.g. `public enum PlayerMovement { Up, Down, Left, Right }` and `public enum NPCDirection { Up, Down, Left, Right, UpLeft, UpRight, DownLeft, DownRight }` .. for the second you could even work with flags so you can have multiple states at once like `[System.Flags] public enum NPCDirection { Up = 1, Down = 2, Left = 4, Right = 8 }` so you can generate combined directions `var upleft = NPCDirection.Up | NPCDirection.Left` or `var upleft = (NPCDirection)5;`